# Как растянуть фотографию с помощью Python?

Tags: python

Как растянуть фотографию с помощью Python? Знаю про библиотеку Content aware image resizing (PyChair), но не совсем понимаю как она работает. Доки читал. Возможно это можно сделать с помощью Pillow. Знатоки нужна помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код со своей попыткой решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью функции thumbnail с сохранением пропорций или resize приводит картинку к желаемому размеру без сохранения пропорций

```
from PIL import Image


size = (450, 450)
img = Image.open(path)
img.thumbnail(size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
img.save(outfile, "JPEG")
```